# Mvx does not exist in the current context mvvmcross

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

When binding iOS storyboard to the core library I get problem. Currently the Android app that uses the same core PCL works well.

My problem is to register a singleton:

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IFoo>(new ChangeFoo());
```

I get the message

"The name 'Mvx' does not exist in the current context"

I think I am missing something simple here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`using Cirrious.CrossCore;`

If you don't have it you can add it from "Manage NuGet packages..." under your project->References.  I assume you are familiar with this since you already got the Android App to work...

Comment: Hi. My latest mvvmcross solution dont have a CIrrius package. I have Mvvmcross package only. And it dont recognize Mvx.